# jquery datatables: update table cell after button click

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

we have a table in our page, with a few rows and a custom toggle button at the end.
the table is loaded via html in the page, not via json.

now, the togglebutton at the end posts to a service and sets the follow state of that record in the database.

however, it should also make an update to another cell in that row.
however i'm sure i should not do this via jquery manually but via datatables?

```
$('#tblFollow').dataTable({
    sDom: "t",
    aoColumns: [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      { bSortable: false }
    ]
});

$('#tblFollow').on('click', 'a.follow', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    // updating column 'following' here... 
    // but this only changes visually, and not the inner datatables data used for sorting
    var followingCell = $(this).parents('td').prev();
    var txt = followingCell.text() == "1" ? "0" : "1";
    followingCell.text(txt);

    return false;
});
```

[manual example:](http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/gWpes/2/) 
now i have an example, where i change the fields manually, but that's only visual, the datatable still uses its inner data for sorting. So i'm looking for a way to do it better

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

In addition to your code you should update the datatables data as following

```
var rowIndex = table.fnGetPosition( $(this).closest('tr')[0] );
var aData = table.fnGetData( rowIndex  );
aData[2] = txt; //third column
```

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/8jGB6/)

**And even better solution** would be to use `fnUpdate` to update the data and display in the same time

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/8jGB6/2/)

```
// update column following here... 
var followingCell = $(this).parents('td').prev();
var txt = followingCell.text() == "1" ? "0" : "1";

var rowIndex = table.fnGetPosition( $(this).closest('tr')[0] );
table.fnUpdate( txt, rowIndex , 2);
```

---

Also instead of us

```
var followingCell = $(this).parents('td').prev();
var txt = followingCell.text() == "1" ? "0" : "1";
```

use

```
var aData = table.fnGetData( rowIndex  );
aData[2] //use it to check if the value is 0 or 1
```

Comment: that works like a charm. sorry the optimization you did at the end, to check the value on aData instead of on the text of the cell, was not necessary but interesting.  I only used it in my example jsFiddle... my own code already knew the text from data properties on the button. but i didn't want to complicate the jsFiddle too mutch.  still interesting. thanks.

Comment: Pay attention, this solution seems to work only with legacy dataTables. In dataTables 1.10.7 I use `table.cell(targetCellSelector).data("new text").draw();`.